# controlling depth parameter in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following code:

```
#import necessary packages
 import os
 from scrapy.selector import Selector
 from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter
 from scrapy.item import Item, Field
 from scrapy.settings import Settings
 from scrapy.settings import default_settings 
 from selenium import webdriver
 from urlparse import urlparse
 import csv    
 from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
 from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
 from scrapy import log

#set maximum DEPTH_LIMIT to 3
 default_settings.DEPTH_LIMIT = 3
  .....
  .....
  .....
```

The spider works beautifully, but for some reason it goes to the sites that has depth greater than 3. How can I limit the depth so that the spider doesn't get into the sites that have depth greater than 3? Like shown above ,I tried to control the depth in my own way but it didn't work....thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the way overridding the default settings as you do is correct. The common way is:

```
from scrapy.conf import settings


class MySpider(SOMESPIDER):

    def __init__(self):
        ......
        settings.overrides['DEPTH_LIMIT'] = 3
        ......
```

There are other methods to override settings. Doc is [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.20/topics/settings.html).

I have investigated some source code of scrapy and sorry for that I can't tell how scrapy uses its settings whether set from the default or from users. But the following source code will do you a favor and it shows a proper way scrapy uses to override the default settings: [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/commands/crawl.py#32)

Answer (score 3):

For new versions use

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider'

    custom_settings = {
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': '3',
    }
```